# Dataflow: Override the Coder used by Shuffler

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We're using Dataflow to run a set of operations over Python objects. Because our objects aren't Pickle-able, we're using the `DillCoder`, which generally works well. We can either override the `_fallback_coder` of the coder registry, or supply the coder to the Reader or Writer - either works.

However, when our objects need to be shuffled, we get an error that our object can't be pickled from the `PickleCoder`.

I think that the Dataflow Worker Shuffler doesn't take into account the coder registry and instead always uses the `PickleCoder`. Is that right? Is there a way to override that?

Full stack trace below. Job-ID is `2018-01-25_15_21_50-3249437741466877997`.

Thanks

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 69, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 233, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
    self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value)))
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 415, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
    self._invoke_per_window(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 306, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_per_window
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 431, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise new_exn, None, original_traceback
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 189, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 84, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 90, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 63, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 81, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 730, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    def get_estimated_size_and_observables(self, value, nested=False):
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 739, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 260, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self.encode_to_stream(value, out, nested)
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 298, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
    self.fallback_coder_impl.encode_to_stream(value, stream, nested)
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 154, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
    return stream.write(self._encoder(value), nested)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 497, in <lambda>
    lambda x: dumps(x, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), pickle.loads)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed [while running 'run reversion/FlatMap(run_reversion)']
```

EDIT:

Here's a reproducible example. Job-ID was `2018-01-30_11_53_22-14709945294406059840`

```python
import zlib
import argparse
from itertools import chain

import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.coders.coders as coders
from apache_beam.coders.coders import (DillCoder, coder_impl, maybe_dill_dumps,
                                       maybe_dill_loads)
from apache_beam.coders.typecoders import CoderRegistry, FirstOf
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class ObjectCoder(DillCoder):
    """
    Coder that allows multi-line pickles to be read, and compresses the output
    After an object is pickled, the bytes are encoded as `unicode_escape`,
    meaning newline characters (`\n`) aren't in the string.

    # but now we're doing compression, do we need to do the newlines?

    Previously, the presence of newline characters these confues the Dataflow
    reader, as it can't discriminate between a new object and a new line
    within a pickle string
    """

    def _create_impl(self):
        return coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl(
            dill_compress_dumps, dill_compress_loads)


def dill_compress_dumps(stream):
    # in Py3 this needs to be `unicode_escape`
    return zlib.compress(maybe_dill_dumps(stream)).encode('string_escape')


def dill_compress_loads(stream):
    # in Py3 this needs to be `unicode_escape`
    decoded = stream.decode('string_escape')
    try:
        decompressed = zlib.decompress(decoded)
    except zlib.error:
        decompressed = stream
    return maybe_dill_loads(decompressed)


def add_obj_to_coder_registry(coder_registry):
    """
    Add Dill to the middle of the coder registry - after the deterministic
    coders but before the Pickle coder
    Use like: `add_obj_to_coder_registry(beam.coders.registry)`
    """
    assert isinstance(coder_registry, CoderRegistry)

    primitives_coder = coders.FastPrimitivesCoder(fallback_coder=ObjectCoder())

    # https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apacpycohe_beam/coders/typecoders.py#L93  # noqa
    fallback_coders = [coders.ProtoCoder, primitives_coder]

    coder_registry._fallback_coder = FirstOf(fallback_coders)


known_args, unknown_args = argparse.ArgumentParser().parse_known_args()

default_options = dict(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='PROJECT_ID',
    temp_location='gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/temp/',
    staging_location='gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/staging/',
    max_num_workers='100')

# from https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py  # noqa
default_options_args = ['--{}={}'.format(attr, value)
                        for attr, value in default_options.items()]

default_args = chain(
    default_options_args,
    ['--save_main_session'])

args = chain(unknown_args, default_args)

add_obj_to_coder_registry(beam.coders.typecoders.registry)


def produce_unpicklable():
    def double(x):
        return x * 2
    return double


p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(list(args)))

items = p | beam.Create([x for x in range(10)])

unpickleable = items | beam.Map(lambda x: (x, produce_unpicklable()))

shuffle = unpickleable | 'use shuffler' >> beam.GroupByKey()

r = p.run()
```

Comment: I think that coder type information should be propagated down the pipeline but it looks like some operations might not support it and always resort to the default. In any case, can you provide a minimal code (with non-Pickleable objects that trigger this specific error)?

Comment: I think the issue is that the user code isn't run before this code (i.e. the shuffler is run separately). In the stack trace, there is no line of user code. 

I'll put together a code sample

Comment: Can you try registering the coder using 'coders.registry.register_coder()' ? See example 'https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/group_with_coder.py'.

Comment: @chamikara I'm fairly confident that won't work - I've literally replaced the fallback coder, so it's not like it's not registering. But if you still think it's worth a shot, I'll give it a go - let me know

Comment: @chamikara Can you look at the backend code that's not open source (e.g. `dataflow_worker/executor.py`) and see if my user code gets run in that process? My hypothesis is that the user code isn't run in the shuffler, and so can't change the coder

Comment: Yeah, it's great if you can try out the standard interface as well as the example I provided. I'll try if I can reproduce the error at my side.

Comment: Confirmed this doesn't work, nor is there any user code in the stack trace. JobID: `2018-02-08_11_17_41-10921717503922327615`

Comment: Additionally, a similar pipeline fails if the _result_ is not pickle-able (e.g. if the `beam.Map(lambda...` were the final task)